# Symfony (Silex) radio choice form builder does not render attr

Tags: symfony, twig, silex

I'm trying to add attributes to my rendered radios

```
$builder
    ->add('myRadios', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
            'one' => 'uno',
            'two' => 'due'),
        'multiple' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'testClass'),
        'expanded' => true
```

the output is:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label required">Myradios</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <label for="form_one_0" class="required radio">
            <input type="radio" id="form_one_0" name="form[one]" required="required" value="uno" />
            <span>Uno</span>
        </label>
        <label for="form_two_1" class="required radio">
            <input type="radio" id="form_two_1" name="form[two]" required="required" value="due" />
            <span>Due</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

no references to class='testClass'

I can't find any issue online

Answer (score 1):

Try this way Adam,

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')
        ->add('myRadios', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'one' => 'uno',
                'two' => 'due'),
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => true,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'testClass'),
        ))
        ->getForm();
```

it works:

```
<div id="form_myRadios" class="testClass">
     <input type="radio" id="form_myRadios_0" name="form[myRadios]" required="required" value="one">
     <label for="form_myRadios_0" class="required">uno</label>
     <input type="radio" id="form_myRadios_1" name="form[myRadios]" required="required" value="two">
     <label for="form_myRadios_1" class="required">due</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How does your twig code look like? And which form template do you use?

You use a custom form template because

`<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label required">Myradios</label>
    <div class="controls">`
 is definitely not standard Symfony!

Comment: Looks like you're using MopaBootstrapBundle which is not standard Symfony and might be the cause of your problem: https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig#L56