# How can I create a checkBox - Silex framework

Tags: php, checkbox, silex

I'm using a `Silex framework`. I want change an `inputText` by a `checkBox` for multiple choice.
This following my code:

```
$app->get('/Chart/{A}/{B}/{C}/{D}', function(Request $request, $A, $B, $C, $D) use ($app) {

if ($app['security']->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        ///start form 
        $user = $app['security']->getToken()->getUser();
        $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')->setMethod('GET')

         ->add('Article', 'text', array(
                    'data' => '',
                    'required' => FALSE))
```

I changed it by:

```
->add('Article', 'choice', array(

'choices' => array('A' => 'B',
                        'B' => 'B',
                        'C' => 'C',
                        'D' => 'D',
                        'OTHERS' => 'OTHERS'),
                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'empty_value' => 'ALL',
                    'empty_data' => NULL
                ))
```

But this one is for a unique choice.
How can I change it to a checkbox for multiple choice ?
I want the `checkBox` for `multiple choice` like this:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it but I believe you can set the `multiple` option like this:

```
->add('Article', ChoiceType::class, 
    array(
        'choices' => 
            array('A' => 'B',
                        'B' => 'B',
                        'C' => 'C',
                        'D' => 'D',
                        'OTHERS' => 'OTHERS'
            ),
        'required' => false,
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true
    )
);
```

For more, refer to [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#multiple) documentation.

---

Regarding the line break you could try by changing the last part to this (*again: not tested by me*):

```
 ...

'expanded' => true,
'choice_label' => function ($value, $key, $index) {
    return $key.'<br />';
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work almost is similar.

Comment: Could you try with the updated one? I'm afraid atm I don't have means for testing :)

Comment: Yes I tested it. It display a Selection list with multiple options, I mean for a unique choice, it not an <input type="checkbox">

Comment: Hmm.. I'll test it out when I find some time, in the meantime you can try once more with my last edit.

Comment: When I add 'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true it'll display next to each other not like this picture above. Please I'm need to your help, how can I create it.

Comment: Not sure about that but I think you can use [`choice_label`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label) or [`choice_attr`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr) attributes to add HTML classes to your choices.

Comment: The option "choice_attr" does not exist. Known options are: "action", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "choice_list", "choices", "compound", "csrf_field_name".....

Comment: You can use `attr` to add a class to your choices like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16641791/2568469), and then add CSS for the new class.